# get the sum of 2 column and mutliply them in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

can somebody help me with this?

```
 SELECT x.poid
      , COUNT(b.poitemsid)
      , SUM(SUM(unitprice) * SUM(qty))
      , recievedate inventoryrecieved as c 
   FULL 
  OUTER 
   JOIN poitems b 
     ON c.poitemsid = b.poitemsid 
   FULL 
  OUTER 
   JOIN purchaseorder x  
     ON b.poid = x.poid 
  GROUP 
     BY x.poid 
      , podate
      , b.poitemsid
      , recievedate
      , unitprice
      , qty
```

Comment: `SUM(col1*col2)`

Comment: Somebody is more likely to be able to help you if you explain what you're trying to do. First glance though, you seem to be summing all the prices and then multiplying by the sum of all the quantities. That's probably not useful, I suspect you may be after just sum(unitprice * qty)

Comment: You also probably don't want to group by the fields you are summing, since that will give you lots of individual sums of only one value at a time, i.e. just the value itself.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
select po.POID, Count(p.POItemsID),
       Sum(UnitPrice * Qty),
       RecieveDate
from InventoryRecieved ic join
     POItems p
     on ic.POItemsID = p.POItemsID join
     PurchaseOrder po
     on p.POID = po.POID
group by po.POID, p.POItemsID, RecieveDate;
```

Notes:

- The solution to the problem is a simple `sum()` of a product.
- MySQL does not support `full outer join`.  A basic inner join should be  fine.
- Your `group by` only needs the unaggregated columns from the `select`.
- It is recommended to use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.